# Where to ask about a verbatim code search?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question for alternatives for browser and non-browser based verbatim code search tools. However, I know that such a question:

- Will be closed at StackOverflow because it's not about actual code
- Will be closed at SuperUser because about a web service

Is there an appropriate StackExchange website where I could ask this question?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a shopping recommendation and hence [off topic pretty much everywhere on the Stack Exchange network](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)